# Read from text file without spaces

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read from text file and store in String array.

First word is store in functionName[0], ignored space and the remaining are to be stored in functionName[1] without spaces with a condition that words starting with # are ignored.

```
read 3 #this is to be ignored
find 4
skip 5
insert test message for insert
```

Below code works for read, find and skip but for insert, it only captures insert in functionName[0] and test in functionName[1].
How can I amend such that functionName[1] will save "testmessageofrinsert" without spaces because I need to use hash the string for other use.

```
public static void read(String filename) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            String line;
            reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(filename));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] functionName = line.split("\\s+");

                String newLine = "";

                for (String strg : functionName) {
                    if (strg.startsWith("#")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        newLine = strg + newLine;
                    }
                }

                functionCall(functionName);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove spaces to hash the string?

Comment: I indicated that because with spaces, I'm not sure if I can store in String array. I just need to store "test message for insert" for hashing. not necessarily removing spaces.